# PHP If/ Else statement not working. Just following 'IF' line

Tags: php, string, if-statement

As simple as it seems, I dont know why this isn't working.

I have a form with a few drop down selects that if $message_type is equal to other, the message is constructed out of just the details from $details.

If $message_type is anything else, it should string together a message.

The variables are being passed and have checked that it is exactly 'Other' that is being passed through to the page using echo's so there is no spelling mistake.

At the moment, whatever the message type, it always just creates the message to be just $details and does not follow the 'else' line if it does not equal 'Other'.

```
    if ($message_type = 'Other'){$message = $details;
}
    else {$message = "Action to do: ".$message_type." On ".$user." Extra Details: ".$details;
}
```

Any help as this is now really confusing me.

Thanks

Comment: you are assigning with = not making a comparison with ==

Comment: On a side note: a decent IDE would've warned you for that.

Comment: That's why I prefer Yoda conditionals...

Comment: Sweet, thanks for your help all. Knew it was just a silly error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($message_type = 'Other'){$message = $details;
}
    else {$message = "Action to do: ".$message_type." On ".$user." Extra Details: ".$details;
}
```

you have `if ($message_type = 'Other')`
you should have `if ($mesage_type == 'Other')`

I suppose it is just writing mistake, so I wont be telling what is the diferance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($message_type == 'Other')
{
    $message = $details;
}
else
{
    $message = "Action to do: ".$message_type." On ".$user." Extra Details: ".$details;
}
```

`$message_type = 'Other'` is alway true

Answer (score 2):

*What* you did wrong were already explained by the other answer, but "why" does this happen? It's simple: `=` is the assignment operator and like any other operator in PHP (and many (all?) languages) the operator has a retun value, that is in this case the value of the assignment. PHP now cast this to a boolean and therefore it is `true`

```
if ($message_type = 'Other'){ /* .. */}
if ('Other'){ /* .. */}
if (true){ /* .. */}
```

Comment: +1 for saying that it will evaluate the *result* of the assignment as a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You need two equal signs

```
if ($message_type == 'Other') {
-------------------^
    $message = $details;
} else {
     $message = "Action to do: ".$message_type." On ".$user." Extra Details: ".$details;
}
```

One equal sign is the assignment operator, so you are saying "$message_type is equal to 'Other'" instead of "if $message_type is equal to 'Other'"